# Android emulator permission

Tags: android

Android emulator is not asking for any permission while running an application which uses protective functions like dialing a number etc. Is the user consent asked only while running on a mobile and not on emulator?

Answer (score 12):

permission is asked on install time, once the app is installed, it will use all the functionality of phone that was asked on install time.

So on Emulator, you just hit the run button and it installs automatically, that's why you are thinking it is not asking permission.

if you go into Settings->Applications->YourApp 
you will see the details of the permission your app will use.

Answer (score 4):

Update for newer emulator versions where the Settings app can't be found on the launch screen anymore: Open the notifications by swiping from the top of the screen to the bottom, do it again to enlarge the quickstarter for bluetooth, flashlight etc. On the bottom-right you will find a gearwheel to open the Android settings.